# SVG triangle can't fully show one angle

Tags: svg

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <g groupfor="line" transform="translate(30,40)">
    <path stroke="#3a5f8b" fill="none" stroke-width="20" d="M 0.00 132 L 31 0.00 L 62 132 Z"></path>
  </g>
```

Above is the svg code I used.

Comment: where is the "below code"

Comment: Made example visible

Comment: Code is visible now.

Comment: try `<path stroke="#3a5f8b" fill="none" stroke-width="20" d="M 0.00 132 L 31 12 L 62 132 Z"></path>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the [`stroke-mitrelimit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-miterlimit) and [`stroke-linejoin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linejoin) to get whatever effect you are after. If you want the corner to be sharper, you need to increase the mitre limit.

Comment: Alex, thanks for your help, it works after set stroke-miterlimit.